# Python dice class

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, dice

I've built a simple dice class utility for rolling dice. It supports weighted rolling, and usage is fairly simple. Here's the code.

```
from random import choice

class Die(object):
    """
    The Die class represents a sided die
    with n amount of sides. Sides can be
    weighted. For example:

        die = Die({
            "side_name": weight
            ...
        })
    """
    def __init__(self, dice_sides: dict):
        self.dice_sides     = dice_sides
        self._choosing_data = []

    def _populate_choosing_data(self):
        """
        Populate self._choosing_data with data
        to choose from, based on weight.
        """
        for key, value in self.dice_sides.items():
            if type(value) == int:
                for weight in range(value):
                    self._choosing_data.append(key)
            else:
                raise TypeError("Weight value needs to be an integer.")

    def select_side(self):
        """
        Select a random side from the list of
        sides based on their weights. The side 
        name will be returned as a string.
        """
        self._populate_choosing_data()
        return choice(self._choosing_data)
```

Here's some example usage. The dictionary structure is as follows. `{"side name": weight}`.

```
import dice_utils

die = dice_utils.Die({
    "1": 1,
    "2": 5,
    "3": 1,
    "4": 2,
    "5": 7,
    "6": 1
})

print(die.select_side())
```

I'd like some suggestions for improvement. I especially don't like how I have to allocate a private variable as well, so if there are any suggestions for improvement there, I'd like some.

Comment: Why do you call `_populate_choosing_data` in `select_side` rather than `__init__`? If this is a worry about mutability, **should** a `Die` be mutable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly inherit from `object` in Python 3 - all classes are *new-style*. And you can't do it for backwards compatibility if you're also using function annotations, which 2.x doesn't support.

---

Your docstrings aren't accurate, for example:

```
class Die(object):
    """
    The Die class represents a sided die
    with n amount of sides. ...
```

but there is no `n` in the code! Also, note that per [the guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> Multi-line docstrings consist of a summary line just like a one-line
>   docstring, followed by a blank line, followed by a more elaborate
>   description.

---

`.select_side()` seems like an odd name for the method - typically, this would be named `.roll()`, as that's what you do with a `Die`!

---

You have some minor violations of [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), for example:

> Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:
>
> - ...
> - More than one space around an assignment (or other) operator to align it with another.

and yet:

```
self.dice_sides     = dice_sides
self._choosing_data = []
```

---

```
if type(value) == int:
```

is **not** the correct way to test whether `value` is an integer, for two reasons:

1. `int`, like the other built-in types (and `None`), is a *singleton*, so you can and should use `is int` (identity) for comparison rather than `== int` (equality); and
2. [`isinstance(value, int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is a much better approach, as it supports inheritance correctly (e.g. if you create some `int` subclass, for example a `PositiveNonZeroInt` for the weights and number of sides, it will still be accepted).

---

Initialising `_choosing_data` in `__init__` but populating it in `_populate_choosing_data` is a little awkward, and leaves you open to bugs... which you've introduced:

```
>>> die = Die({1: 1, 2: 2})
>>> die.select_side()
1
>>> die._choosing_data
[1, 2, 2]
>>> die.select_side()
1
>>> die._choosing_data
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]  # oh dear!
```

This is a bit inefficient in the best case, where the `dice_sides` never get changed (the proportions of the different items remain the same) and can lead to incorrectly-distributed outputs in the worst case, where the user tries to alter the proportions.

Minimally, you can move `self._choosing_data = []` to the start of `_populate_choosing_data`. However, it would probably be better to call `_populate_choosing_data` from `__init__`, and protect `dice_sides` as read-only using a property:

```
class Die(object):

    def __init__(self, dice_sides: dict):
        self._dice_sides = dice_sides.copy()
        self._populate_choosing_data()

    @property
    def dice_sides(self):
        return self._dice_sides.copy()

    ...
```

As `dice_sides` is a mutable object, note that I've introduced `.copy()` to prevent the user from accidentally changing the version that the instance uses internally.

---

There is also space for some inheritance here; consider:

```
class Die(object):

    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        return random.randrange(self.sides) + 1


class WeightedDie(Die):

    def __init__(self, sides, weights):
        super().__init__(sides)
        self._weights = {side: weights.get(side, 1) 
                         for side in range(1, sides+1)}
        ...

    def roll(self):
        ...
```

This lets the user specify the minimal information required; your example:

```
die = dice_utils.Die({1: 1, 2: 5, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 7, 6: 1})
```

becomes:

```
die = dice_utils.WeightedDie(6, {2: 5, 4: 2, 5: 7})
```

This only supports numerical sides at present (note that I've altered your example accordingly, and removed the extraneous whitespace), but could be adapted to allow non-numerical sides.

---

Weighted random choices are a pretty common problem, and have been solved in various ways that you could adopt; see e.g. [*"A weighted version of random.choice"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679694/3001761).

Answer (score 3):

`_populate_choosing_data` does two things:

1. Validates member attribute
2. Populates "choosing data"

It would be better if it did just the one thing its name says.

The parameter name of the constructor is "dice_sides", but we're in a Die class, so dice is already implied clearly enough. What's not so clear is that the dictionary is a mapping of sides to weights. You could make it obvious by using a better name.

And when you iterate over this dictionary, `key` and `value` are generic names that don't mean much. It would be better to call the loop variables side and weight, to make this clear and intuitive.

Lastly, " choosing data " isn't a great name. How about "choices"?